# Is there an alternative for the soon-to-be-deprecated pandas.util.testing.assert_produces_warning?

Tags: python, pandas, testing

I don't see one in the [API](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.errors.ParserWarning.html), though the warning suggests it should be available:

```
In [1]: import pandas

In [2]: from pandas.util.testing import assert_produces_warning
/home/mghenis/anaconda3/bin/ipython:1: FutureWarning: pandas.util.testing is deprecated. Use the functions in the public API at pandas.testing instead.
  #!/home/mghenis/anaconda3/bin/python


In [3]: from pandas.testing import assert_produces_warning
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-38c6b9f78373> in <module>
----> 1 from pandas.testing import assert_produces_warning

ImportError: cannot import name 'assert_produces_warning' from 'pandas.testing' (/home/mghenis/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/testing.py)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They've moved this into the "private" API in [_testing.py](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/_testing.py).

Really you should probably be using [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/3.0.2/recwarn.html)'s `with pytest.warns()` methods directly for this and I suspect that's why they moved it, though I can't find the discussion around that choice.

Answer (score 1):

- The source code for [`assert_produces_warning`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/_testing.py#L2527) states that it is a wrapper for [`warnings.catch_warnings`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.catch_warnings).

  - It seems using `warnings.catch_warnings` is the best option.
  - [Examples](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/_testing.py#L2567)
- From pandas 1.0.0 Release Notes:

  - The `pandas.util.testing` module has been deprecated. Use the public API in `pandas.testing` documented at [Testing functions](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/reference/general_utility_functions.html#api-general-testing) ([GH16232](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16232)).
- As per [pandas 0.25 Test Warnings](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/development/contributing.html#testing-warnings) for `pandas.util.testing.assert_produces_warning`

  - *We prefer this to the [`pytest.warns`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#pytest-warns) context manager because ours checks that the warning’s stacklevel is set correctly.*